# isAssignableFrom always returns false

Tags: java

```
public class Admin extends Ability implements Listener 

And


public class Admin implements Listener 


System.out.println(Admin.class.isAssignableFrom(Listener.class)); // returns false
```

Hello I'm checking if class is implementing Listener. however, it always returns false! (Look above code!!) what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) documentation states that it:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false.

`Admin` is not a superinterface of `Listener`. Flip them around and you should get the behavior you desire.

Comment: I hate this method name so much. I find it unintuitive, and I need to carefully re-read the documentation any time I want to use it (which, admittedly, is extremely rare). I would have literally preferred `theThingOnTheLeftIsASuperclassOfTheThingOnTheRight`. :-)